# Weasyprint doesn't render images (Python)

Tags: python, html, pdf, file-conversion, weasyprint

I am writing a python script that generates a html file out of some images and svg files, which later should be converted into a pdf file.
For the conversion I am using [weasyprint](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/index.html), but for some reason it doesnt render the images, only the according alt-text.
Here is a screenshot of the html file rendered in Chrome:

[image: rendered html]

But the generated pdf looks like this:

[image: generated pdf]

Here is the code that should generate the pdf:

```
html = HTML(filename="path/to/file")
html.write_pdf("path/to/output/file")
```

And here is the according html file:

```
<img src="C:/Users/jonas/Documents/Dev/PythonLabel/bin/LABEL_SVG.svg" alt="SVG of Label" />
<div class="sn-number">3253343345</div>
<img class="qr-code" src="C:/Users/jonas/Documents/Dev/PythonLabel/bin/qrcode.png" alt="qrcode" />
```

I dont know what causes the problem, but Firefox isnt able to render the images either, but Chrome and Brave manage to do so. Maybe both problems have a similar reason.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it to work, but its not a pretty solution.
I figured out, that weasyprint was able to get images and SVGs from actual webpages like stackoverflow. So I made a little flask app that would only serve the one html file, and after the PDF was created I just stopped the flask server.

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process

app = Flask(
    __name__, static_folder=path/to/static/folder)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    with open(path/to/html, "r") as f:
        html = "".join(f.readlines())
    return html


def start_server():
    app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Process(target=start_server)
    server.start()
    sleep(4)
    print("Generating PDF...")
    html = HTML(
        "http://localhost:5000").write_pdf(path/to/output/file)
    server.terminate()
    server.join()
```